# $\operatorname{Lip}(\alpha) \subset C^0$

Tags: real-analysis

Proof that

> $\operatorname{Lip}(\alpha) \subset C^0[a,b]$ where $\operatorname{Lip}(\alpha) = \{f: [a,b] \to
>  \mathbb{C}: M_f = \sup_{s\neq t} \frac{|f(s)-f(t)|}{|s-t|^\alpha} <
>  \infty\}$

$C^0[a,b]$ is the set of continuous functions in $[a,b]$

Hi, I am trying to prove this statement using definition of continuous function for all $ \epsilon$ we have a $\delta$ such that $|x-y| < \delta$ then $|f(x)-f(y) < \epsilon|$.

If we take a $\delta= \frac{1}{\epsilon^{1/\alpha}}$

So, for $|s-t|^\alpha < \delta^\alpha $, we have that $ |f(s)-f(t)|<|f(s)-f(t)| {|s-t|^\alpha} < \epsilon \delta^\alpha $

I am really confused, please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty much there. You have that $$|f(t)-f(s)|\leq M_f |t-s|^\alpha<M_f\delta^\alpha=\epsilon$$ if $|t-s|<\delta,$ where we take $\delta=(\epsilon/M_f)^{1/\alpha}$ (provided $M_f$ is non-zero, as this is obvious otherwise).

Comment: Tank you so much!!